# What’s the point of the [open-source] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source) tag’s [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/open-source/info) starts with “*QUESTIONS ABOUT LICENSING ARE OFF-TOPIC. You may ask questions about open source licensing on https://opensource.stackexchange.com.*” which is right, but “open source” is all about licencing.

The existence of this tag looks like an invitation to post off-topic questions. The description continues with “*This tag is for asking about writing programs that interact with open source software.*” but it’s not clear how it matters to a programming question whether the software the questioner is interacting with is “open source” or not.

Indeed when I looked through questions tagged with [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source) (skipping the off-topic ones), I didn’t find any example of a question where this tag helped categorizing the question. When “xyz” is an open-source software, we could add [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source) to every question tagged with [xyz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xyz) which obviously would not add any value. On the other hand, I can’t imagine a scenario where one [xyz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xyz) question is more specific to [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source) than another one (unless it’s an off-topic licensing question).

Note further, there is no [closed-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closed-source) tag which supports that the license is irrelevant. Or any question not tagged with [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source) is considered to be about [closed-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closed-source), which would imply that millions of question are wrongly tagged.

Comment: Title suggestion: [open-source], closed arms

Comment: Revoke [open-source] license

Comment: [open-source]: the Cathedral and the Bizarre?